# How to pass NSObject class particular data from one class to another class in ios

Tags: ios, nsobject

In my ios app I have created one NSModel Object for displaying tableList and when I tapped on tableList row I want to take that particular model class object data to another class

How can I do this?

### my code:

```
NSMutableArray * mainArray;

//TableList Delegate Methods:

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return mainArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"HistoryCell";

    // Similar to UITableViewCell, but
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[MaintableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil){

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    model1 = mainArray[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = model1.Name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = model1.MasterId;

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    ViewController1 *Controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController1"];
    Controller.indexPosition = indexPath.row;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:Controller animated:YES];
}

@end
```

### ModelObject1:

```
#import "ModelObject1.h"

@implementation ModelObject1

@synthesize MasterId,Name;

-(void)loadingservices :(id)mainDictionary{

    NSLog(@"loadingservices %@",mainDictionary);

    Name = [mainDictionary objectForKey:@"Name"];
    MasterId = [mainDictionary objectForKey:@"MasterId"];
}

@end
```

Comment: You can pass model data through segue or any other way.

Comment: so how can we get that Model obejct data in another class

Comment: i want to display ModelObject1 data in my View controller1,how is it's possible?

Comment: it type mistake you just need to create object of your model in View controller 1

Comment: can u explain me with some code? please

Comment: @Krish Please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try like below:

1) Create one model object in your `ViewController1`

```
 @property (strong,nonatomic) ModelObject1 *modelObj;
```

2) Write below code in `viewDidLoad` of `ViewController1`,

```
 modelObj = [[ModelObject1 alloc]init];
```

Then Replace your didSelect method like this,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    ViewController1 *Controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController1"];
    Controller.indexPosition = indexPath.row;
    ModelObject1 *model = mainArray[indexPath.row];
    Controller.modelObj = model;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:Controller animated:YES];
}
```

Then get you data from model class in `viewDidLoad` of `ViewController1`

```
e.g, NSLog("%@", modelObj.Name);
```

This way you can pass model class object to other view controller. Hope this will help you.

Comment: i am getting null value in Viecontoller1

Comment: Have you alloc-init in viewDidLoad? Check i edited did select method.

Answer (score 0):

Create one model object in your Destination View controller

> @property (strong,nonatomic) ModelClass *job;

in your did select method get that model data and pass it

```
ModelClass *SelectedJob;
SelectedJob = [muarrJobs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

JobDescriptionViewController *obj = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"JobDescription"];
    obj.job = SelectedJob;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
```

Comment: i am getting null value

Comment: Name is=======>(null) like this i am getting in my Viewcontroller1

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        ViewController1 *Controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController1"];
        model1 = mainArray[indexPath.row];
        Controller.modelVal = model1;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:Controller animated:YES];
    }
```

Another ViewControllerB:

ViewControllerB.h

declare the property Value

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)modelName *modelVal;
```

ViewControllerB.m

print the name value in `viewDidLoad`:

```
NSLog(@"%@",modelVal.Name);
```

hope its helpful

Comment: i am getting null value

Comment: Name is=======>(null) like this i am getting in my Viewcontroller1

Comment: you will get the model value in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, please check NSLog(@"%@", model1.Name);